# get restricted page after login using requests,urllib2 python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests

I'm trying to login in [this](http://selleraccounts.snapdeal.com/) page using python-requests

```
headers = {
    'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/33.0.1750.152 Chrome/33.0.1750.152 Safari/537.36'
}

data = {
    'username':myusername,
    'password':mypassword,
}
r = requests.post(url,data=data,headers=headers)
```

I tried to print the returned response via `print r`
and output was `<Response [200]>` but html page was of login page but I was expecting html of someother page we will be redirected to after login.

Comment: You should *not* set the content type header; requests will take care of that for you depending on the requirements of the form. A POST defaults to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The login form contains a several hidden fields:

```
<input type="hidden" name="lt" value="LT-1314930-GPfgUfyUj5eRY4RCaoa1Xi3gi5Jfsf" />
<input type="hidden" name="execution" value="e3s1" />
<input type="hidden" name="_eventId" value="submit" />
```

Most likely the first, and perhaps the second field are auto-generated and tied to the session. You'll need to load the login page first (using a session), parse those fields and include them in your POST.

The reason you get 200 responses is that the site *redirects* unauthorized requests back to the login page; check `r.history`, there will be one or more 302 responses in that list.

You could use BeautifulSoup to parse this, or use [`robobrowser`](http://robobrowser.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), which combines `requests` and BeautifulSoup, together with a dedicated form handler to make a browser-like framework for navigating a website:

```
from robobrowser import RoboBrowser

browser = RoboBrowser(history=True,
    user_agent='Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/33.0.1750.152 Chrome/33.0.1750.152 Safari/537.36')
browser.open('http://selleraccounts.snapdeal.com/')

form = browser.get_form(id='fm1')
form['username'].value = myusername
form['password'].value = mypassword
browser.submit_form(form)
```

Comment: whoaa !! this looks amazing tool. but what do I do now. I'm lost here. Do I still need to use requests/urllib in my program or robobrowser alone can do all things. would be great if you just give me hint how to proceed further. I tried to look robobrowser tutorials but all I find API.

Comment: Robobrowser is relatively new, so example code is still sparse. You don't need anything else, really. You can get the original response object as `browser.state.response`.

Comment: thanks :)
I used `browser.parsed` for complete text. is it correct?
I have one more query. will robobrowser maintain session automatically, I dont want to login every time.
simillar to `requests.Session()`

Comment: Yes, `.parsed` is the BeautifulSoup parse tree. The `browser` object has several methods that let you search it too (like `find()` and `find_all` and `select`). Robobrowser uses a requests Session under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:
1. Just because the response code is 200 for you login requests doesn't mean it's succeeding. It could be that the developer isn't following REST guidelines for whatever reason and returns a 200 with the body indicating an error.

1. When I tried to login to the website your provided with my Chrome developer tools enabled, I inspected the traffic and observed that the website is transmitting more than just the username and password. Specifically there are 4 other fields:

   ```
   username:adb  
   password:asdf    
   lt:LT-1315009-vg7Xm5MTSfBYkGNuaiUbAFZqVZNmoP   
   execution:e2s1   
   _eventId:submit   
   submit:LOGIN
   ```

I suspect that some of them are anti-CSRF tokens, which you might need to scrape from the login page that you initially receive, but regardless I don't think the login request will go through unless you provide the correct value for each of these fields.

Comment: Your browser session shows that both the `lt` and `execution` fields both vary per session and need to be provided.