# Replicate browser actions with a python script using Fiddler

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to log in to a website using python and the `requests` module.

My problem is that I am still seeing the log in page even after I have given my username / password and am trying to access pages after the log in - in other words, I am not getting past the log in page, even though it seems successful.

I am learning that it can be a different process with each website and so it's not obvious what I need to add to fix the problem.

It was suggested that I download a web traffic snooper like [Fiddler](http://fiddler.wikidot.com/mono) and then try to replicate the actions with my python script.

I have downloaded Fiddler, but I'm a little out of my depth with how I find and replicate the actions that I need.

Any help would be gratefully received.

---

My original code:

```
import requests
payload = {
    'login_Email': 'xxxxx@gmail.com',
    'login_Password': 'xxxxx'
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    p = s.post('https://www.auction4cars.com/', data=payload)
    print p.text
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the browser developer tools, you may see that the login POST request needs to be submitted to a different URL:

```
https://www.auction4cars.com/Home/UserLogin
```

Note that also the `payload` needs to be:

```
payload = {
    'login_Email_or_Username': 'xxxxx@gmail.com',
    'login_Password': 'xxxxx'
}
```

I'd still visit the login page before doing that and set the headers:

```
HOME_URL = 'https://www.auction4cars.com/'
LOGIN_URL = "https://www.auction4cars.com/Home/UserLogin"

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers = {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36"
    }
    s.get(HOME_URL)

    p = s.post(LOGIN_URL, data=payload)
    print(p.text)  # or use p.json() as, I think, the response format is JSON
```

Comment: Thank you. When I do this, I get the message output: 

{"Success":false,"ExceptionMessage":"Please check your login details and try again. If you have forgotten your password use the link provided.","IsAdmin":false}

But the username and password are definitely correct. I have even copied and pasted them directly from the script into the browser to confirm.

I don't know if it's relevant, but when when I try https://www.auction4cars.com/Home/UserLogin in my browser, I get a 'page not found'

Comment: @user1551817 ah yeah, okay, one more thing was wrong - the payload - please check the updated answer. Thanks.

Comment: That got it. Thank you so much, I've been struggling with this for a while!